# Chart FX 6.2 is not displayed on windows 7 clients

Tags: chartfx

We have an ASP.net application that uses charFx 6.2. It works on windows XP clients but the clients who run Windows7 can not see the chart. Any help in this regard is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 users probably have a newer version of Internet Explorer which is incompatible with the older version of ChartFX.

You could try to update ChartFX or run an older version of IE (through something like Citrix) on the Windows 7 machines.